# Eclipse LDT doesn't run local Lua interpreter

Tags: eclipse, lua

I have problem with Eclipse LDT. When I run my test Lua app, it executes just fine using JNLua inside JavaVM environment. But [according to this tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Koneki/LDT/Developer_Area/User_Guides/User_Guide_1.0#Managing_Interpreters), when I reference native `lua.exe` interpreter and set it in Run Configuration as Runtime Interpreter, Run Configuration disables Launch script: and nothing is executed. When I run a same script with a same native local Lua interpreter 5.1, everything works just fine.

So, what is the problem with LDT? Has anyone had the same experience?

## EDIT

I've managed to run local `lua.exe` from Lua Development Tools stand-alone product, but still it doesn't work as Eclipse plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's a bug.
I guess when you register your interpreter, you uncheck the checkbox : "Accept file as argument"

This mean LDT will not manage the file to launch (that's why the Launch script is disabled)

The standard lua interpreter support file as argument and -e option, so the two check box should be checked. (It's the default value)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug ... Would you mind filing it in the Koneki [bug tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Koneki&component=LuaTools&version=1.0)?